# Can I use JavaScript to upload only part of a selected file?

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I have a web app that needs to process CSV files. However prior to processing, I'd like to give the user the option to "preview" how we plan to treat each column. In this case, even if the file has hundreds of thousands of lines, I'd like to first only process the first dozen or so.

Comment: Have you looked into using the `slice` method on the `File` object (to create a `Blob` with the first n number of bytes), then using FileReader to read out the contents of that `Blob` and then place them into some DOM element(s) for presentation?

Comment: @Ray no I haven't (this file stuff is new to me) but thanks for the suggestion will look into that!

Comment: Are you looking to do all of this client-side, or do you really need to send only a portion of the file to the server for some reason?

Comment: Need to send portion of file over to server. Will be doing stuff like hitting a database, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty easy to simply send a portion of the file over to the server.  There, you can do whatever you like with it.  The trick is determining how many bytes of the file are necessary.  If you don't care exactly how many "columns" are contained in the portion sent to the server, you can just pick a byte offset, let's say 1000 bytes.

So, you have a `File`.  Presumably you are using a browser the uses the File API.  In such a browser, you can get a handle on the `File` via the `DataTransfer` object from drop event or via the the `files` property of a `<input type="file">` element.  Let's assume you already have the `File` object.

First, grab the first 1k of the `File`:
`var myFilePart = myFile.slice(0, 999);`

`myFilePart` is a `Blob`.  You can then send this `Blob` to your server via XHR2:
`xhr.send(myFilePart)`

Answer (score 0):

How about processing the first 100 Lines in the csv-file with JavaScript as the preview?

Comment: Do you mean client-side? I need to things like hit a database and rather not go that route.